# How do I conditionally add a leading zero to a column of numbers?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, sql-update

forgive me... I'm a noob in this field.
I have googled this already, but I'm not entirely sure of the info I found as it's not exactly matching my use case.

In my db I have an accounts table with addresses. the addresses are broken up into street, city, state, country, and postalcode. everything was imported from a csv file which somehow stripped the leading 0 on every number... some postal codes have leading zeros (newjersey for example) so the application that pulls from the db is throwing some errors when opening these accounts.
The column is already varchar so find and replace should be pretty simple. I need to add the zero only to strings with 4 characters in them.
In theory, I COULD just run this:

```
UPDATE account SET columnName=postalcodes(nums,5,0);
```

the problem is a handful of accounts have the 4 digit postal extension as well. doing this would (as I understand it) wreck those fields... or am I wrong?

so basically, how do I do an update in this situation, to add a zero only if the field is 4 characters long?

Comment: "... only if the field is 4 characters long"   `WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(thefield) = 4`   I strongly encourage us to *test* expressions in a SELECT statement, before we use them in an UPDATE statement...   `SELECT id, thefield, somexpression FROM mytable WHERE ...`

Answer (score 2):

Use `lpad()`:

```
update account set postal_code = lpad(postal_code, 5, '0')
```

This left-padds the string with `0`s if it is less than 5 characters long (note that if the string is longer than 5 characters, it is truncated to the target length).

Comment: Does this address the 'handful of accounts' bit?

Answer (score 1):

not sure how to specifically upvote comments, but spencer7589 and GMB helped.
I used this:

```
SELECT id, shipping_address_postal_code FROM account WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(shipping_address_postal_code) = 4;
UPDATE account SET shipping_address_postal_code = lpad(shipping_address_postal_code, 5, '0') WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(shipping_address_postal_code) = 4;
SELECT id, billing_address_postal_code FROM account WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(billing_address_postal_code) = 4;
UPDATE account SET billing_address_postal_code = lpad(billing_address_postal_code, 5, '0') WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(billing_address_postal_code) = 4;
```

basically I did select as recommended by spencer7593 to check what data would be modified. then once I was satisfied it was safe to do so, I used where to single out the fields with 4 characters or less--also suggested by spencer7593--and lpad as suggested by GMB (because I misunderstood the original query I was copying).

thanks guys!

Comment: You can mark your own question as correct by ticking the grey tick mark to the left of the answer, if it solved your issue (obviously it did, hence the answer posted)